# Welchen Fall benutzt man im Falle mehrerer Verben?

Tags: grammatical-case

Wenn man einen Satz baut, worin es mehrere Verben gibt, die sich auf dasselbe Objekt ausrichten, aber unterschiedliche Fälle erfordern, welcher Fall sollte  für das Objekt benutzt werden?

Beispiel:

> Die Frage ist, ob das Geld **das/dem** Land wirklich **bevorteilt** oder doch mehr **schadet**?

Comment: Ich würde den Beispielsatz anders formulieren: "Und, ob das Geld das Land wirklich bevorteilt oder **ihm** doch mehr schadet?". Aber ob solch eine Umformulierung immer möglich ist, ist fraglich.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solche Sätze baut man lieber nicht. Man bildet dann einen Satz, der zwei Objekte hat, die aber ein und dasselbe Objekt sind, nur in verschiedenen Fällen:

> Und, ob das Geld das Land wirklich bevorteilt oder ihm / dem / diesem Land usw. doch mehr schadet?

Comment: "*baut man lieber nicht*" würde eher sagen: "... kann man nicht (fehlerfrei) bauen!"